# Get the sum of maximums using Influxdb query

Tags: influxdb

I have a service that monitors the number of users per host.

I need a query that takes the maximum number of users per host, every 5 minutes, and then sums them all, i.e. it returns how many users I have in the system across hosts.

I need that the result can be plot as a line chart to see the evolution.

When I use the following query, I can see the maximum number of users in each host, every 5 minutes:

```
SELECT max("users.connected") AS "users" 
FROM "telegraf"."autogen"."customer" 
WHERE time > now() - 12h 
GROUP BY time(5m), "host" 
FILL(0)
```

The chart is as follows: [image]

However, when I try to group these series using the following subquery, it returns a series of zeroes and when only data from one host is available (i.e. the rest hosts return zero users), the metrics from that host are returned.

```
SELECT sum("users") 
FROM 
   (SELECT max("users.connected") AS "users" 
    FROM "telegraf"."autogen"."customer" 
    WHERE time > now() - 12h 
    GROUP BY time(5m), "host" 
    FILL(0)) 
GROUP BY time(5m)
```

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this aggregation? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to limit time range and add `WHERE time > now() - 12h` to outer query.

Comment: It didn't fix the issue, but fixed another related one. I explain in the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was with the `fill(0)` statement.
When I replace it with `fill(null)` it works as expected.

```
SELECT sum("users") 
FROM 
   (SELECT max("users.connected") AS "users" 
    FROM "telegraf"."autogen"."customer" 
    WHERE time > now() - 12h 
    GROUP BY time(5m), "host" 
    FILL(null)) 
GROUP BY time(5m)
```

Additionally, when in the datetime selector we pick an absolute date, we need to add the `WHERE` clause to the outher query as @Yuri Lachin suggested. In that case it would be adding `WHERE time > :dashboardTime: AND time < :upperDashboardTime:`, so the whole query ends up being:

```
SELECT sum("users") 
FROM 
   (SELECT max("users.connected") AS "users" 
    FROM "telegraf"."autogen"."customer" 
    WHERE time > :dashboardTime: AND time < :upperDashboardTime:
    GROUP BY time(5m), "host" 
    FILL(null)) 
WHERE time > :dashboardTime: AND time < :upperDashboardTime:
GROUP BY time(5m)
```